# Java heap out of memory but not really

Tags: java, heap-memory, velocity, turbine

So getting this error when trying to render a page on using Velocity via Turbine servlet. The thing is I have tons of memory, and the servlet itself never crashes. It just fails on this request. The page it's trying to render is maybe 10M.

Anyone have any thoughts/suggestions?

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271) at
 java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113) at
 java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221) at
 sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282) at
 sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125) at
 sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135) at
 java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220) at
 java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157) at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTReference.render(ASTReference.java:321)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:109)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:271)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:128)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTBlock.render(ASTBlock.java:94)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:271)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTIfStatement.render(ASTIfStatement.java:128)
 at
 org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.SimpleNode.render(SimpleNode.java:271)
 at org.apache.velocity.Template.merge(Template.java:296) at
 org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.mergeTemplate(Velocity.java:492) at
 org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.mergeTemplate(Velocity.java:461) at
 org.apache.turbine.services.velocity.TurbineVelocityService.executeRequest(TurbineVelocityService.java:455)
 at
 org.apache.turbine.services.velocity.TurbineVelocityService.handleRequest(TurbineVelocityService.java:321)
 at
 org.apache.turbine.services.velocity.TurbineVelocity.handleRequest(TurbineVelocity.java:109)
 at
 org.apache.turbine.modules.layouts.VelocityOnlyLayout.doBuild(VelocityOnlyLayout.java:155)
 at org.apache.turbine.modules.Layout.build(Layout.java:91) at
 org.apache.turbine.modules.LayoutLoader.exec(LayoutLoader.java:138) at
 org.apache.turbine.modules.pages.DefaultPage.doBuild(DefaultPage.java:191)
 at org.apache.turbine.modules.Page.build(Page.java:91) at
 org.apache.turbine.modules.PageLoader.exec(PageLoader.java:136)
```

`JAVA_OPTS= -Xms4096M -Xmn2048M -Xmx13128M`

Memory usage under top never gets above 100M.

Comment: Is it reproducible? If so, could you find out memory details using Visual VM (or) JConsole before rendering the page?

Comment: Very, happens every time I try to generate a page past a certain size.  I can probably work around it, but it's just frustrating because I don't understand why or how it's happening. I'm definitely not running out of heap space (maybe for that thread or something?).

Comment: Line 2271 of Arrays.java is `byte[] copy = new byte[newLength];`, but that should allow up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5` of length.  I don't know the issue, but I comment this with the hope that it sparks someone's mind.

Comment: @Vulcan: I think that means, Arrays class trying to reserve MAX_VALUE-5 bytes, but heap saying I can't because at least those many bytes are not available. There might be some memory leak which is filling up the heap while loading this page.

Comment: what is the size of the array it tries to create at this point?

Comment: @Nambari `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5` bytes aren't attempted to be reserved; the creation of an array uses the memory it needs to, and no more.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit or 64-bit Java?  What is the overall process size?  How much RAM and swap are in the machine?  How much swap is available?

I saw something like this once and it was because the computer was out of swap space.  So even though my max heap was something like 16GB and the JVM was only using 2GB of heap, Java still game an OutOfMemoryException because when it went to increase the heap the operating system-level memory allocation failed (because all my RAM and swap was exhausted).

Comment: Are you certain the OPTS were picked up? Can you run this against jconsole to see for sure the arguments are set correctly.

Comment: If you a minimum heap size of 4 GB, it don't see how you can have more than 100 MB used. I suspect you are using more memory than you think.

Comment: The java opts were tweaked that large in an attempt to fix the problem. They are being picked up, and I use more memory in other parts of the application. For example I use iText to generate very large pdf reports, and it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the relevant velocity template? Maybe there is some endless loop which makes the resulting document infinite in size?

Maybe you can redirect the OutputStream to stdout just to see what is generated up to the point where allocation fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your `-Xmn` is causing the problem, by reserving too large a chunk of the initial heap for the young generation. I would suggesting running your server without this, and seeing what happens.

My reasoning for this is that the failure occurs on `ByteArrayOutputStream.grow()`, which is creating a new array that is some percentage larger than the existing one. Large arrays (> 512M) get put directly into the tenured generation, so if too much space is reserved for the young generation, there may not be enough available in tenured.

Another possibility is that your rendered template is far larger than you think it is. Although the most likely cause for this is a loop, and I don't see that in the stack trace.

Finally, add the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` option when starting. If your output arrays are growing too large, you'll see this in the heap dump (use `jhat` to examine the dump).

Comment: +1 - Good answer.  I deleted mine and voted yours up.